# How to pass data on ajax with form and a value of a global variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am uploading a file to my server and I want to save the name of the file to my database. I am able to save it to my database. I also want to save the name of the user together with the name of the file, but the problem is I cannot pass the name of the user to the controller from the blade because it is not included on the form of the button for uploading. The name of the user is a global variable, is there any possible way to pass it to ajax together with the form? What do I need to add on my code? Thank you in advance!

I have tried passing the username like this

```
data: "refNumber2="+refNumber2+formData,
```

but still it doesn't pass the refNumber.

This is my html code for file Uploading:

```
<form method="post" action="{{URL::to('/store')}} " enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmuploadFile" class="frmuploadFile">

                            <input name="image" type="file" class="image">

                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                        <button type="submit" name="btn" id="btn-upload" class="btn btn-default col-sm-15">Upload a File</button>

                    </form>
```

This is my ajax:

```
$('form').on("submit",function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ url ('/store')}}",
                    type: 'POST',      
                    data: "refNumber2="+refNumber2+formData,
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,   
                    success: function(data){
                    }
                });                
            });//form
```

This is My Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $refNumber = $request->get('refNumber2');
        if (Input::hasFile('image')){
            echo "UPLOADED <br>";
            $file = Input::file('image');

            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'.'.time().'.'.$extension;

            $file->move('uploads', $fileNameToStore);
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        }

        DB::table('i_di_thread')
            ->insert(['refNumber'=>$refNumber,'message'=>$fileNameToStore]);
    }//Upload File
```

Comment: Why don't you pass another hidden field like your _token field ?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another hidden field in your from and put your global variable value.

```
<form method="post" action="{{URL::to('/store')}} " enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmuploadFile" class="frmuploadFile">

  <input name="image" type="file" class="image">

  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  // add another hidden field here
  <input type="hidden" name="refNumber2" id="refNumber2" value="{{ your_global_variable }}">

  <button type="submit" name="btn" id="btn-upload" class="btn btn-default col-sm-15">Upload a File</button>

</form>
```

Comment: like this: <input type="hidden" name="refNumber2" id="refNumber2" value="{{ refNumber2 }}">

Comment: Yes ! You can do that.

Comment: I got an error and it says:    Use of undefined constant refNumber2 - assumed 'refNumber2' (View: C:\wamp\www\Product-Inquiry\resources\views\showInquiries.blade.php)

Comment: It means you don't pass a variable named refNumber2 from your controller.

Comment: I want to pass the value of the global variable from the blade to the controller.

Comment: OMG @Md.Sukel Ali Thank You for your answer!! I just forgot to change my data: 'refNumber2='+refnumber2+formData to data:formData Thank You very Much

Answer (score 0):

you can add another hidden field here nammed userName for exemple

```
  <input type="hidden" name="userName" id="userName" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}">
```

and in your Controller you can get it by

```
 $request->get('userName')
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer Mr @abderrahime sanadi i have also tried it and it works!